# Meaning of memory related terms?

Tags: windows, memory, theory

While playing with memory profiling in delphi, although it applies to any language I've found some terms about used memory which I don't completely understand. Could someone explain (or refer to a good document or manual) the meaning of the following terms?

- Working set size
- Pagefile used
- Committed memory
- Uncommited memory
- Private Usage (from the PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX struct)
- PagedPool
- NonPagedPool
- Total Address Space (from a THeapStatus in delphi memory manager)
- TotalAllocated (from a THeapStatus in delphi memory manager)

The msdn has a [brief description of each field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684874%28VS.85%29.aspx) but the intricacies of their meaning is beyond me. Things like, when does each section grow? what are they used for? if you measure one value, what is it telling you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Memory Management Glossary](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/a.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should read series of brilliant articles by Mark Russinovich: Pushing the Limits of Windows.

- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Physical Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Virtual Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx)
- [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Paged and Nonpaged Pool](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx)

Comment: +1 that looks like a lovely set of articles. But to asker: You really need to take the time to understand how a page-based virtual memory system works for those terms to get any real meaning.